# Prolog: print out value of variable during execution

Tags: prolog, factorial

I'm following [Prolog Tutorial](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/1.html) to learn Prolog.

This piece of code load `factorial` program in REPL and get the result of `factorial` function from `What`.

> ?- ['factorial.pl'].           /* 1. Load a program from a local file*/

```
true.
```

> ?- listing(factorial/2). /* 2. List program to the screen*/

```
factorial(0,1).

factorial(A,B) :-  
           A > 0, 
           C is A-1,
           factorial(C,D),
           B is A*D. 

>true.
```

> ?- factorial(10,What).     /* 3. Compute factorial of 10 */

```
What=3628800
```

Now I want to have the result printed in the program and execute it as a script:

```
factorial(0,1).

factorial(A,B) :-
           A > 0,
           C is A-1,
           factorial(C,D),
           B is A*D.

main:-
    factorial(10, var).
```

> $ swipl -q -f factorial.pl -t main

Nothing printed out. So I add `write(var).` to `main`:

```
main:-
    factorial(10, var).
    write(var).
```

get error:

> ERROR: /SomeFolder/factorial.pl:11:   No permission to modify static procedure `write/1'

How do I print out the variable value during execution?

Comment: (1) Variables must start with a capital letter. so `var` should be `Var`. (2) You have a period after `factorial(10, Var)` instead of a comma.

Comment: @lurker Uh...`Singleton variables: [Var]`

Comment: You won't get "singleton variable" warning of you (1) change BOTH instances `var` to `Var` and (2) use a comma instead of a period after `factorial(10, Var)`. Please follow all the instructions. :)

Comment: @lurker Oh, my god...Too long have I been waiting for this answer. Please write down as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While defining a predicate there shouldn't be a '.' except for when you are ending it. You should use a ',' instead.
the correct code would be-
main:-
     factorial(10,Var),
     write($Var).
Also notice the variables. In prolog you should type the names of variables in capital, if not, then they would be considered predicates. Also see that while using write predicate to print Var, I have used $ before Var. If the $ sign won't be there the write function will print the memory location of Var and not its value